# Java regex - how to chop String into parts

Tags: java, regex, javafx, textflow

I am trying to chop a text into an `Array` (or `List`).
For example the `String`

```
String str = "so this will be _ITALIC_ and this will be *BOLD* and so on";
```

shall be split into this:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"so this will be ", "_ITALIC_", " and this will be ", "*BOLD*", " and so on"};
```

i worked out some things with `regex` like:

the `Pattern`s for finding my matches:

```
public static final Pattern Italic = Pattern.compile("_(.*?)_");
public static final Pattern Bold = Pattern.compile("\\*(.*?)\\*");
public static final Pattern Strike = Pattern.compile("~(.*?)~");
```

i also found out how to split the text with my patterns:

```
// more to be added
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(Italic + "|" + Bold + "|" + Strike);
String[] parts = ptn.split(input);
```

which results in:

```
"so this will be "
" and this will be "
```

but i am not able to find a way, without loosing the information of the pattern.

Why i do this?
i need to transform plain text to formatted text using `javafx.scene.text.TextFlow` therefore i need to find the chunks and create `javafx.scene.text.Text` and apply the formating.

Comment: It feels like you should really be using a *Markdown Tokenizer*. Or you know, a *Markdown Renderer* directly, if that's where you're going.

Comment: You cannot do this with `split`. Java only supports fixed lenght lookahead/lookbehind and in your case you need to check the whole string to determine, if `*` is a "opening" `*` and you need to split before or a "closing" `*` and you need to split after...

Comment: If you really want to do it yourself, and your rules are as simple as you described, then `(?=\b_|\*\b)|(?<=_\b|\b\*)` would work for you. I can't explain why, though, 'cause your question just got closed.